# Yagi gain reduction when using off frequency (2.3Ghz WiMax system using 2.4Ghz WiFi Yagi)

Tags: antenna, wifi

I have a new WiMax 2.3Ghz broadband service that has marginal reception. As the frequency 2.3Ghz used is close to WiFi I am thinking I can use a cheap WiFi yagi instead of a much rarer (and expensive) 2.3Ghz yagi to improve reception.

I'm aware that I won't get as much gain at 2.3Ghz versus 2.4Ghz as the antenna won't be perfectly tuned but I believe yagi antennas are somewhat tolerant to being used a little outside their tuned frequency.

Can anyone explain or point to more details on yagi performance outside its tuned frequency so I can work out if I should DIY a 2.3Ghz tuned one? I'm OK to lose 3dB of gain but not much more.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: The bandwidth of a yagi is a few % of centre frequency. There are some calculators available, e.g. http://www.giangrandi.ch/electronics/anttool/gain.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bandwidth of a Yagi antenna is just one of the parameters that was considered in the design. Therefore, there is no definitive answer, since the performance at 2.3 gHz would vary between different WiFi antennas.

Having said that, there is a high likelihood that most WiFi antennas would work. The reason is that WiFi needs 100 megahertz of bandwidth (2401 MHz to 2495 MHz), and it would be difficult to design an antenna with that wide a bandwidth without also being sensitive at 2300 MHz (WiMax).

But more importantly, a Yagi can be designed for a very wide range of gains, so it really is just a matter of getting one with more gain than your current WiMax antenna. Keep in mind: The more elements in the Yagi, the higher the gain but also the more directional it is. It may be more difficult to point a higher gain Yagi.